# Convert QTextStream to std::stringstream

Tags: c++, qt, stringstream, qt5.4, qtextstream

I have a few text files embedded in a .qrc file. However, my back-end project is not based on Qt and a couple of times in the Qt front-end project, I have to call `A::read(std::string const& filePath)`-like functions that utilize `std::ifstream` to read the file. Of course, there's no way for `std::ifstream` to find the file stored in Qt Resource System, so I started thinking about conversion.

Using `std::stringstream` was the first thing that popped into my head:

```
std::istringstream iss(QTextStream(&file).readAll().toStdString());
// I didn't find any conversion functions in QTextStream
```

But I hope that there's something better. (I don't need to preserve unicode.)
I will accept even solutions closer to the root of the problem - qrc.

Comment: How big are your files? Can you keep the whole text in memory at once? `std::string content = QTextStream(&file).readAll().toStdString()` like a simple approach.

Comment: @Simon Warta You mean pre-loading? That's not the issue. Problem concerns reading a file from Qt Resource System with standard streams.

Comment: But why do you need to use the standard streams? Why does it matter how you get from a QRC URL to a file's content?

Comment: @Simon Warta Well, as mentioned, back-end project does not use Qt and it's API for loading files are functions, that take filepath. So I overloaded these functions to take `std::istringstream`s too. `std::istringstream` can be filled with data read by `QTextStream`. Parameter could be also `std::string`, but it will end up constructing `std::istringstrem` because I need to read formatted text.

Comment: Then the code you posted is exactly what you need. `iss` is a std::istringstream containing a copy of the content of the file. Now you can read out of `iss`.

Comment: @Simon Warta Thanks, I wasn't sure.

Comment: If you are experiencing performance issues in this part – and only then, you can use a binary stream from Qt and construct the std::string directly from a QByteArray because now you convert every text to UTF-16 (in QString) and back into UTF-8 (in std::string).